# How do I make this long if statement less cumbersome?

Tags: python, if-statement, comparison-operators

Here is an `if` statement from a method I was making (never mind what it's for):

`if str.lower(char) == "a" or str.lower(char) == "e" or str.lower(char) == "i" or str.lower(char) == "o" or str.lower(char) == "u":`

There must be a shorter way to write this `if` statement, right? Maybe something like:

`if str.lower(char) == ("a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u"):`

Is there a way to make equality (or any comparison for that matter) distribute among many terms in a similar way? It seems to me that something like this would make for easier to read code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `in` keyword is designed for this sort of thing:

```
if str.lower(char) in "aeiou":
    ...
```

Comment: You should also do `char.lower()`.  The other form is unsightly. :)

Comment: I agree. Unless it seems particularly important, I try to focus only on the question being asked - fixing up their code in other ways tends to muddy the answer.  If I make both changes, they might mistakenly think the other fix is somehow relevant to the use of the `in` keyword.

Comment: I would convert the string of vowels into a list first; this prevents matches such as 'ae' or 'eiou'. Additionally, use ```char.lower()``` instead of ```str.lower(char)```. Here you go: ```if char.lower() in list('aeiou'): …```